# No "Add New Table" option in Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

I was following a tutorial on how to make a simple database in Visual Studio in this [site here.](https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-59-creating-a-database-in-visual-studio)  The version of Visual Studio I use is the Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1

I was able to follow all the steps to make a database until I got stuck on one part. This part of the tutorial asks me to make a table by simply pressing "Add New table", but in the Visual Studio that I used, there's no option "Add New table" as shown below...

[image]

How can I activate this "Add New Table" in the Visual Studio?

I can't go further if I can't make a table.

Comment: Is that .mfd a file? In that case you might just need to edit the file to add a table manually.

Comment: Not sure if this is required - do you have [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/jj650015?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) installed?

Comment: To capture the screen, use the `PrtSc` key on your keyboard, and use `MS Paint` to edit the screen capture before uploading. Using camera on a smart phone is not a good idea.

Comment: Or in any recent version of Windows (7+), use the Snipping Tool to take a snippet of exactly the part of the screen you want: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots

Comment: @EpicKip it is a mdf file...I'll try to edit it....

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't know....I never heard of that tool before. I thought making a simple database is pretty straightforward, without needing additional tools other than the Visual Studio....

Comment: @kennyzx you're right, using cellphone camera to take pics on screen sucks....I use PrtSc key instead....I'll update my pics...

Comment: @Rob If I'm going to use Snipping Tool, the buttons "Refresh" and "Properties" would disappear...

Comment: @LalakiugBabaye, that's what the "Delay" option is for in Snipping Tool, set the delay to 5 seconds (or less if you think you can be quick, pro tip: You probably won't be! :) then click "New", get the menu visible and then wait for Snipping Tool to kick in

Comment: @EpicKip I've just replace my pic with a better one...:-)

Comment: @Rob I've just replace my pic with a better one...:-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've just replace my pic with a better one...:-)

Comment: @kennyzx I've just replace my pic with a better one...:-)

Comment: @LalakiugBabaye, I don't have a definitive answer for you, but,.. could you install Visual Studio 2017 (Community is freely available) and continue the tutorial in that? I *suspect* something has gone a bit screwy in your VS2012 install but having not used it for a while I don't know what to suggest to try and get past it, I'm afraid :)

Comment: @Rob I found how to get the "Add New Table" option now...I just downloaded the "SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2012" software....Now I can make tables now...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate the "Add New Table" option in Visual Studio 2012, just download the [SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/jj650015?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

After we downloaded this software, open it.

After you open it, try to check if the Visual Studio 2012 now got the "Add New Table" option. If you still don't see the "Add New Table" option in Visual Studio 2012, restart your computer.

You must be able to see the "Add New Table" as shown below after you restarted the computer. It did worked on me.

[image]

If still you don't see the "Add New Table" option in Visual Studio 2012, post the problem on Stack Overflow....